# How to write the equivalent in backbone or ember or any javascript MVC framework of a simple jQuery AJAX call so that i can unit test it

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, backbone.js, ember.js

I need to refactor the whole javascript codebase of the wordpress plugin i'm working on so that i can run unit test on it and i was looking for a place to start. I understand that i need to start using a MVC framework to do unit testing properly and i wanted a little "kick-start". Suppose i have a very basic jQuery AJAX call, how would you write the same code in a MVC framework so that it's unit testable?

```
// Refreshes the multiselect with data from facebook.
$( '.ai1ec-facebook-refresh-multiselect' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Find the spinner and show it
    $( this ).closest( '.ai1ec-facebook-multiselect-title-wrapper' )
             .find( '.ajax-loading' )
             .css( 'visibility', 'visible' );
    var type = $( this ).closest( '.ai1ec-facebook-multiselect-container' ).data( 'type' );
    var that = this;
    var data = {
            "action"     : 'ai1ec_refresh_facebook_objects',
            "ai1ec_type" : type
        }
    $.post( 
        ajaxurl, 
        data,
        function( response ) {
            $( that ).closest( '.ai1ec-facebook-multiselect-title-wrapper' )
                     .find( '.ajax-loading' )
                     .css( 'visibility', 'hidden' );
            if ( response.errors === true ) {
                var alert = AI1EC_UTILS.make_alert( response.error_messages.join( '<br/>'), 'error' );
                $( '#alerts' ).append( $alert );
                return;
            }
            $( ' .ai1ec-facebook-multiselect-container[data-type=' + type + '] .ai1ec-facebook-multiselect ').replaceWith( response.html );
            var $ok_alert = AI1EC_UTILS.make_alert( response.message, 'success' );
            $( '#alerts' ).append( $ok_alert );
        },
        'json'
    );
} );
```

Any javascript MVC example would be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not any association between using a MVC framework and having a *testable* code.

Neither there is a reason for thinking a non MVC framework based code can not be very *testable*.

It is completely possible to move all this code into a MVC implementation and having a result as tedious to test as this one.

The problem I'm seeing in the example code you showed to us is that it lacks in *modularity*. I'm not very *pattern religious* but maybe we can talk about *Single responsibility* here.

What I recommend here is to create isolated methods for all the logic there, organize them, put them into a Class or Utils module, then you will see how easy is to test them, in insolation and in collaboration.

Once you achieve this you can move to a MVC or not, but only because the *testability* of the code it is not a reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i was to a conference recently, the jsDays in ITaly, where they told that to do proper testing and to help modularize the code you had to use a MVC framewrok, hence my question. Can you advise somewhere i could start reading about uit testing in javascript?I'm familiar with it in PHP but i find a little harder modelling classes in JS. I also found out this book, gave you read it? http://tddjs.com/

Comment: Using a MVC framework forces you to a minimal organization, but **minimal**. Not in every case a MVC framework is helpful besides without a natural organizational spirit in the programmer you can finish with a mess with or without the MVC.. even worst with the MVC if your movements are against its way. The book you link above looks nice but doesn't look to be _in the wave_ :) (I don't see any Jasmine of Sinon reference on it).. anyhow if you are just starting with all of this any thing you will read will be recomendable, just start for any thing.

Comment: I've heard about Jasmine at the conference. Well thanks for your help, i'll document myself and try to put all the pieces together to start my refactoring :)